# QDialog with loading bar is not displaying on time

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6

I have an application that has a QMainWindow and a back-end controller that handles all events. One of these events from QMainWindow emits a signal that invokes this method in the controller.

```
def add_files(self, file_paths):
    try:

        for file_path in file_paths:

            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

            "Some other working code here"

            self.silent_save()
            self.main_widget.update_file_display()

    except Exception as e:

        self.logger.error()
```

I also have a QDialog class with a loading bar that looks like this.

```
class FileLoadingScreen(QDialog, Ui_FileLoadingScreen):
    def __init__(self, loading_gif_path, parent=None):
        super(FileLoadingScreen, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)

        # Setting up the loading.gif animation.
        self.movie = QMovie(loading_gif_path)
        self.loading_label.setMovie(self.movie)

        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

    def start_animation(self, width, height, geometry):

        self.resize(width, height)
        self.setGeometry(geometry)
        self.movie.start()
        self.show()

    def stop_animation(self):

        self.movie.stop()
        self.close()
```

I've tried a number of ways of invoking the start_animation method. Called start_animation using another thread (Timer issue), called it from the controller method, called it from within the QMainWindow, called it using a signal emitted from QMainWindow to the Controller. The thread method didn't work at all for obvious reasons, but all other methods produce the same outcome, the loading dialog displays, but only after the add_files method finishes executing. I know it's a problem with who has execution control of the main execution thread, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Assuming that the backend controller lives in the main thread, the for-loop blocks the main event loop until after the files have loaded. If you haven't done so already you could try running the for-loop where you load the files on another thread.

Comment: @Heike is there a direct way in which I can run that loop in another thread, or do I need to create a worker class to pass it to?

Comment: @BobFromBilling please provide a [mre]

Comment: @BobFromBilling you need a separate class.

Comment: @musicamante I figured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I just want to say thank you to everyone who posted, it was a much-needed sanity check. Below is my solution, but I don't recommend doing it this way unless you are under budgetary and time constraints like me. Ideally, the code from my controller's add_files method should be placed in a separate helper class running on its own thread and just signaling back to the controller. However, my solution is working nicely for what it is.

```
@pyqtSlot(list)
def add_files(self, file_paths):

    self.call_loading()

    t2 = Thread(target=self.start_file_copy, args=[file_paths])

    t2.start()

def start_file_copy(self, file_paths):

    try:

        for file_path in file_paths:

            file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)

            "Some worker code here"
            self.silent_save()
            self.main_widget.update_file_display()

        self.done_loading.emit()

    except Exception as e:

        self.logger.error()

def call_loading(self):

    self.file_loading_screen.start_animation(self.main_screen.width(), self.main_screen.height(), self.main_screen.geometry())

@pyqtSlot()
def close_loading(self):

    self.file_loading_screen.stop_animation()
```

Comment: I don't understand how being in budget/time constraints should prevent you to use a simple basic class that just implements its `run()` method, which not only is simpler, but also much clearer (and cleaner) from the modularity point of view.

Comment: Simple, to implement an additional class with the necessary code that was excluded in the "Some worker code here" portion would require a considerable amount of rework and subsequent testing. As I stated in my answer, I agree with you completely. If it's possible a separate QRunnable class or similar would have been the best solution. I wouldn't have gone straight to criticizing, but that's just me.